# Android: SearchableInfo is null when using packageNameSuffix in Gradle build script

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, searchable

I encountered that the method `getSearchableInfo` always returns null during `SearchView` initialization if I use the `packageNameSuffix` in the project's Gradle build script.

**SearchView initialization:**

```
final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName);
mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
```

**Project's build.gradle:**

```
android {
    [...]
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

If the package suffix is not used, the given `componentName` is `ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.MapActivity}` and the `SearchView` as well as its associated `SuggestionsProvider` work fine.

But if `packageNameSuffix` is set to `".debug"`, the given `componentName` is `ComponentInfo{com.example.android.debug/com.example.android.MapActivity}` and the `SearchManager` returns `null`, instead of returning the respective `SearchableInfo` object.

Does anyone know how to get the right `SearchableInfo` from the `SearchManager`? Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

Eugen Martinov mentioned in the comments that this behaviur could have to do something with an improper or missing authorities renaming. But i also configured a build type dependent naming of the authorities, that i omitted in the initial post for the sake of simplicity.

**Project's build.gradle:**

```
android {
    [...]
    sourceSets {
        debug {
            java.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/java'
            ]
            java.srcDirs = [
                'src/debug/res',
                'src/main/res'
            ]
        }
        release {
            java.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/java'
            ]
            java.srcDirs = [
                'src/release/res',
                'src/main/res'
            ]
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

**src/debug/res/values/build-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="cfg_app_name">App - Debug</string>
    <string name="cfg_authorities">com.example.debug.SuggestionsProvider</string>
    <string name="cfg_maps_key"><!-- some key --></string>
</resources>
```

**src/release/res/values/build-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="cfg_app_name">App</string>
    <string name="cfg_authorities">com.example.SuggestionsProvider</string>
    <string name="cfg_maps_key"><!-- some other key --></string>
</resources>
```

**src/main/res/xml/searchable.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/action_search_hint"
    android:label="@string/cfg_app_name"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="false"
    android:queryAfterZeroResults="true"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="@string/cfg_authorities"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="3" />
```

Installing both the debug (with the `packageNameSuffix` option) and the release apk on the same device works. I don't get an error like `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]`... But as already said, `SearchableInfo` is `null` then.

Installing both apk withouth the `packageNameSuffix` option leads into the following error: `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES] - Installation failed since the device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.`

Or am i missing something here?

**[/EDIT]**

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but most probably issue with provider authorities in AndroidManifest. Changing package name should also applied with changing authorities

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, but i think/hope this should not be the issue here. i updated the question accordingly.

Comment: My apologise, I should remember that same authorities won't allow to install apps. But I also remember how much time we spent with figuring out non working content providers because authorities. Just to be sure, can you print authority into log?

Comment: No need to apologize. I really appreciate your efforts. I can log the authorities strings from the resources correctly in the debug as well as in the release application. And inside the SuggestionsProvider I use a wildcard pattern for the URIMatcher: ("*", SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, 1). So the actual name should not matter here, right? I think the problem is that SearchableInfo can not be found, because of the altered package name (used in the submitted componentName). But I have no clue why exactly or how to fix this issue...

Comment: Are you sure android:searchSuggestAuthority="@string/cfg_authorities" supports string resources? Have you tried just putting in the string by itself and seeing if that helps?

Answer (score 6):

I am using product flavors that completely changes the package name. I found that by using the `ComponentName(Context pkg, Class<?> cls)` constructor for my search activity I get a valid SearchableInfo.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class));
```

I also had to adjust my provider to use a different package so my searchable xml is in each flavor directory and the provider is listed in the manifest for each flavor as well.
This is my directory structure:

```
src
  main
    AndoridManifest.xml
  flavor1
    res
      xml
        search.xml
    AndroidManifest.xml
  flavor2
    res
      xml
        search.xml
    AndroidManifest.xml
```

main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/actionbar_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".ui.activity.SearchActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.SearchActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/search"/>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:authorities=".provider.SuggestionProvider"
        android:name="com.example.main.provider.SuggestionProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        />
</applicaiton
```

flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <provider
        tools:replace="android:authorities"
        android:authorities="com.example.flavor1.provider.SuggestionProvider"
        android:name="com.example.main.provider.SuggestionProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        />
</application>
```

flavor1/res/xml/search.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="false"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.flavor1.provider.SuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection="title LIKE ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="0"
    >
</searchable>
```

flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <provider
        tools:replace="android:authorities"
        android:authorities="com.example.flavor2.provider.SuggestionProvider"
        android:name="com.example.main.provider.SuggestionProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        />
</application>
```

flavor2/res/xml/search.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="false"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.flavor2.provider.SuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection="title LIKE ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="0"
    >
</searchable>
```

Comment: Got this to work but found a couple of things - the class in the ComponentName() constructor needs to be the Activity which has the android.intent.action.SEARCH intent defined.  Also, the same Activity with the android.intent.action.SEARCH intent needs to be moved out of the main flavor's AndroidManifest.xml and into the flavor1 / flavor2's AndroidManifest.xml.  Other than that I can confirm the solution works perfectly

Comment: @jklp I didn't have to do that at all. I added parts of my manifests and the search xml.