# Searchview doesn't work in flavor build

Tags: android, gradle

Searchview doesn't do anything, it looks like it doesn't load searchable info.
It works perfectly in free build, but it doesn't work in pro version. I've tried disabling proguard, trying both debug and release versions.

Main:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_view).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        rollout {

        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.example.dictionary"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.01"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.rollout
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            renderscriptDebugBuild false
            zipAlign true
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.rollout
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.rollout
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {

        }
        pro {
            applicationId "me.example.dictionary.pro"
        }
    }
}
```

Searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" />
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Search worked fine in the main flavor, but the client-specific flavors had a problem due to having a different app ID (ex: `com.company.app` vs `com.company.app.clientflavor`).

To fix, change

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

to

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, YourSearchableActivity.class)));
```

Hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25533125/2705173).