# Searchable activity not call, when I use applicationIdSuffix '.debug'

Tags: android

When I use debug suffix for debug version, my searchable activity not call. Without suffix all work fine.

build.gradle

```
debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
}
```

Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.search.SearchableActivity"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>

<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".ui.search.SearchableActivity" />
```

searchable.xm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/action_search"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer">
</searchable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It's because `applicationIdSuffix` changes the package name. And here is a trick in searchView initiating, instead of:

```
srchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

you should create new ComponentName:

```
srchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class)));
```

in that case you'll get valid `SearchableInfo`

thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825949/android-searchableinfo-is-null-when-using-packagenamesuffix-in-gradle-build-scr/25533125#25533125) with packageNameSuffix problem